# "execution expired" mongo ruby driver on connecting to replica set

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am keep getting the following error while trying to connect with my mongodb replica set. I am unable to figure out the issue here.

```
2.2.0 :026 > require 'mongo'
2.2.0 :026 > client = Mongo::Client.new(["#{DB[:host]}:#{DB[:port]}"],
2.2.0 :027 >       :database => DB[:name],
2.2.0 :028 >       :replica_set => DB[:replica_set],
2.2.0 :029 >       :user => DB[:user],
2.2.0 :030 >       :password => DB[:password])
D, [2016-01-27T18:20:47.883886 #3743] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Adding mongo-replica-1:27028 to the cluster.
D, [2016-01-27T18:20:49.005494 #3743] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | execution expired
D, [2016-01-27T18:20:50.376267 #3743] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | execution expired
D, [2016-01-27T18:20:58.096017 #3743] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | execution expired`
```

I can access the replica set using mongo command from bash

```
mongo mydb --host mongo-replica-1 --port 27028 --username myuser --password mypass
```

with the above command I can access mongo and run read data after runnning

```
> db.setSlaveOk()
```

But I am not even able to connect in the first case, it looks like it is connected but keep getting the message "execution expired".

Comment: `MONGODB | execution expired`  this is the message I am getting

Comment: I am using mongo driver version 2.2